# Convert bit column to integer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am converting bit columns of a particular table to integer through an SQL script (this table has some default constraints for default value).

I have to alter the columns for the table, not runtime casting, What script can be used to accomplish this?

Comment: Do u have any default defined on the table column ? In order to see this try to see the  create table structure

Comment: I assume you can't use the Management Studio, is that correct ?

Answer (score 56):

Try using `CAST(columnName AS INT) AS IntValue`.

e.g.

```
SELECT columnName, CAST(columnName AS INT) AS IntValue
FROM table
```

**OR** you can use `CONVERT(INT, columnName) AS IntValue`.

**UPDATE**: If you need to alter the actual metadata of the table, then you first need to drop the constraints then alter the column:

i.e.

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] DROP CONSTRAINT [ConstraintName];
GO
ALTER TABLE [Table] ALTER COLUMN [ColumnName] INT;
```

Then recreate any constraints that you need.

Comment: edited the question please check that i want ddl statement not dml

Comment: for MySQL use `SIGNED` instead of `INT`. Read [MySQL CAST() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp).

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerned about changing the datatype of the column you can use an ALTER query as follows.

```
ALTER TableName ALTER COLUMN ColumnName INT
```

Else, only for display purposes, you can use either the `CAST` or `CONVERT` function:

```
CAST(columnName AS INT) AS IntegerVal
CONVERT(int, columnName) AS IntValue
```

Comment: i have already used this alter script but however when i alter this table it says has some constraints associated to the column and cant be altered..

Comment: sorry forgot to mention you , if u want to alter a column , the column should not contain any values and its dependency table also

Answer (score 2):

None of the provided solutions worked for me. I had to used Signed or Unsigned instead of INT e.g.

SELECT columnName, CAST(columnName AS SIGNED) AS IntValue
FROM table

Hope this helps for new users.

Answer (score 1):

We can't simply alter the BIT column to INT. So I suggest to create the new integer column in the table and then using the CAST, update the new integer column with the existing bit values. Then at last you can drop the BIT column from the table.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to get it working:

```
ALTER TABLE tblname DROP CONSTRAINT DF_tbl_tblname_tblcol
ALTER TABLE tblname ALTER COLUMN tblcol int not null
ALTER TABLE tblname WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_tblname_tblcol] DEFAULT (0) FOR tblcol
```

I have used the above SQL statements to alter the table column along with its constructor.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT CONVERT(BIT,'False') AS test1
SELECT CONVERT(BIT,'True') AS test2

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could extract the bit column as an integer by just using standard `CAST()` command:

```
SELECT
  CAS(Bit_Column AS int) AS Int_Column
FROM
  YourTable
```

However, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, probably you could get a better answer if you provided more details, such as the structure of the table and its constraints.

Comment: i want to change the structure of the table like i have bit fields for broleflag which has default value as false now i want to change the data type for that column from bit to integer and setting default constraint to 0

Comment: Now it's clearer. In such case, you can look at the answer posted by ?Esh, it should do what you're looking for. You just have to add the constraint to the ALTER command.

Comment: i have done that already but the default constraints associated to the field is not allowing me to alter the table column..

Comment: Could you please post the CREATE script for the table and its constraints, together with some INSERT statements? It would allow people to reproduce your environment and test possible solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error related to a default constraint. Thus you have to drop that constraint before altering the column data type...

Try this to find all the constraints based on this table (you just need to find the proper default on your column) or use [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) (SSMS) to generate the script for the table, and this will have the default constraint defintion.

```
select * from sys.all_objects where parent_object_id  = object_id('<tablename>')
go
```

Then first drop the constraint and then alter the column and add the default again.

```
alter table bittoint drop constraint DF__bittoint__col2__45D500F0
go
alter table bittoint alter column col2 int
go
alter table bittoint add constraint DF__bittoint__col2__45D500F0 default 0 for col2
go
```