# How to convert bit column to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to convert a bit column to a integer column, do I need a case and convert function at the same time for this?

```
False = 0
True = 1
```

Comment: A bit column has a value of 0 or 1. So I don't know why it would be an issue to change the column type and still keep your values. Did you try it?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668431/convert-bit-column-to-integer ?

Comment: Did you try:  `cast(col as int)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a conversion, because [`bit`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) is already an integer data type:

> An integer data type that can take a value of `1`, `0`, or `NULL`.

You can use `bit`s in integer expressions without conversion. Here is a short demo:

```
create table demo (b bit, v int);
insert into demo (b, v) values (1,5), (0,4), (1, -2), (0, -5);

SELECT b, v, b+v AS b_plus_v FROM demo
```

Running this [produces](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0f77/1) the following output:

```
B    V  B_PLUS_V
-    -  --------
1    5   6
0    4   4
1   -2  -1
0   -5  -5
```

**EDIT :** (based on this comment: "I'm using Code first EF")

Entity Framework requires that a `bit` column mapped to a `bool` field. One way to work around this requirement is introducing a computed property to your entity class to hide the "Booleanness" of the underlying column, like this:

```
partial class MyEntity {
    // This code assumes that a bool property MyBoolProperty exists,
    // and that it is mapped to the table using EF
    public int MyIntProperty {
        get {
            return MyBoolProperty ? 1 : 0;
        }
        set {
            MyBoolProperty = value != 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With entity framework I the column has to be a Bool, if I change it to a int type the cast fails (I'm using Code first EF).

Comment: @user1361315 I didn't realize that you are talking about EF - you should add a note or a tag to be more specific about this.

Comment: Sql Server converts the `BIT` before adding, no?  The data types bit and bit are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: @DMason You are right, SQL Server does not appear to treat `bit` as a "first-class citizen", prohibiting an addition (unless there's an `int` type in the mix (e.g. [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/34fb2/6) works with `0+b+v`, but does not work with `b+v`). The reason is that when two bits are added together, SQL Server knows that an addition is not going to fit in a `bit`.